# React JSX form field map fails if accessing certain properties

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm attempting to build a form from an array of form fields where each form field looks like this:

```
{
   "name": "state",
   "resource": "customer",
   "type": "TextBox",
   "assetId": "State",
   "label": {
       "text": "State",
       "assetId": "Label"
   }
}
```

However, when I attempt to map it using JSX, the fields don't get successfully displayed if I access certain properties of the object.  Take the following code, which functions correctly:

```
formfields.map(function (formfield, i) {
    var returnfield = <div key={i}>{formfield.name}</div>;
    switch (formfield.type) {
        case "TextBox":
            console.log(formfield.label);
            returnfield = (
                <div key={i}>
                    <label htmlFor="theinput">{formfield.name}</label>
                    <input id="theinput" type="text" value={formfield.name} />
                </div>
            );
            break;
    }
    return returnfield;
});
```

And compare it with the code that fails:

```
formfields.map(function (formfield, i) {
    var returnfield = <div key={i}>{formfield.name}</div>;
    switch (formfield.type) {
        case "TextBox":
            console.log(formfield.label.text);
            returnfield = (
                <div key={i}>
                    <label htmlFor="theinput">{formfield.name}</label>
                    <input id="theinput" type="text" value={formfield.name} />
                </div>
            );
            break;
    }
    return returnfield;
});
```

The astute observer will notice that the only difference between the two is that, in the second, we are logging **formfield.label.text** instead of formfield.label

I'm totally stumped why simply logging an object's grandchild attribute should cause the form to appear empty (i.e., with no fields).  Perhaps I'm running into reserved names or something?  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: If some objects don't have a `formfield.label` property, `formfield.label.text` will throw an error. Otherwise I don't see anything that could cause an issue.

Comment: Felix, you're absolutely right, and that's what's causing the issue.  If you'll post your answer I'll mark it as correct.  But this raises a follow-up question: If the field didn't exist, why didn't I see a javascript error in my developer console?  Is there some weird thing where .map() doesn't allow errors to be raised?

Comment: I think the React framework swallows all errors that are thrown inside the stock component methods. That's why you won't see anything in the console. If you want to change that, you can check this out: http://staxmanade.com/2016/01/developer-friendly-react-component-errors/

Answer (score 2):

> why didn't I see a javascript error in my developer console? Is there some weird thing where .map() doesn't allow errors to be raised?

After recognizing that checking for null is needed in your project well I suggest you use some concepts of javascript functional programming to compose a function that checks for falsely values before applying them in your logic.

You can use **Maybe** functor that returns a Maybe(null) which stops immediately. Before returning a null value to your logic and cause a boom!

You can also use **Either**, this is cool because it's just like maybe but you can also gve some logic to run if the value is falsely.

I have two examples for these suggestions (Copied from jsbin)

```js
    //Key container == Something map can iterate over like an object or an array.
    //And am talking about the lodash / ramda.js curried map that can iterate over object not the   js native one.

    //Using Maybe
    //Url http://jsbin.com/yumog/edit?js,console

    var safeGet = _.curry(function(x,o){ 
      return Maybe(o[x]); 
      //This will return Maybe(null) 
    //if it's some property in a container is not found 
    //which you can check before breaking something
    });

    var user = {id: 2, name: "Albert"}
    
    var ex3 = compose(map(_.head), safeGet('name'));


    assertDeepEqual(Maybe('A'), ex3(user))
    console.log("exercise 3...ok!")



    //Using Either.io

    //url http://output.jsbin.com/bexuc/

    // Write a function that uses checkActive() 
    //and showWelcome() to grant access or return the error
    
    var showWelcome = compose(_.add( "Welcome "), _.get('name'))

    //Here either returns a function you give it on the right if it's truthy 
    //and left if it's falsey (or falsy i don't know english .. )
    // So you get to do something if the property in your container is not present.

    var checkActive = function(user) {
     return user.active ? Right(user) : Left('Your account is not active')
    }

    var ex1 = compose(map(showWelcome), checkActive);

    assertDeepEqual(Left('Your account is not active'), ex1({active: false, name: 'Gary'}))
    assertDeepEqual(Right('Welcome Theresa'), ex1({active: true, name: 'Theresa'}))
```

Links to the libraries.
Maybe: https://github.com/chrissrogers/maybe

Either: https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-eithers

You might also need to check on lodash / ramda to have a full idea on these functional concepts.