# Error handling in React best practices

Tags: reactjs

When rendering a component in React (with many subcomponents) and a JS error is thrown for whatever reason, what's the best way to handle this?  Sure I can catch the error but ultimately the thing you want to render may not be able to because require information is missing.  You can validate ahead of time with `.isRequired` in the propTypes but that just console's a warning when it fails.

Comment: I once answered about error handling in react [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705242/react-jsx-form-field-map-fails-if-accessing-certain-properties/35707025#35707025)

Answer (score 47):

React 16 introduces a new concept called **“error boundary”** to handle errors occur inside React components without breaking the whole app.

> Error boundaries are React components that **catch JavaScript errors
>   anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display
>   a fallback UI** instead of the component tree that crashed.

Error Boundary components have been made possible with a new life cycle method `componentDidCatch(error, info)`. Not like other life cycle methods, this will get called only if any error occurred in during rendering, in lifecycle methods, or constructors of any child (including all grandchildren) component of the component.

In code, Error Boundary component will be something like follows.

```js
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Display fallback UI
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Error occurred!</h1>;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

We can use this Error Boundary component as a normal component in our code.

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <MyComponent />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Now if MyComponent throws any JavaScript error in during rendering, in lifecycle method, or in constructing, `componentDidCatch` of Error Boundary component will trigger and change the state to show `Error occurred!` message instead of the broken MyComponent.

This new functionality comes with another vital implication that you wanted to know before migrating to React 16. Previously, if an error occurs, it leaves corrupted UI even though it doesn't usually work as expected until you reload the page. However, in React 16, if an error hasn't handled by any error boundary, it will result in unmounting of the whole app.

Because of this, you are adding error boundaries to your app appropriately will give a better experience to your user. So users will be able to interact with a part of your app even though some areas of UI have crashed.

Refer [React official documentation on error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) or [this official blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) for more information. They cover almost everything you need to know about this new feature.

Answer (score 7):

Ideally you shouldn't ever have something that would cause a js error. We don't live in a perfect world though so heres a few things I would do to help mitigate them.

**Think about how the code you're writing could break** 
if you are calling a method on a variable, think, "is this always going to be this datatype?"

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  e && e.preventDefault()
  // code here
}

handleSomething = (data) => {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.reduce(...) // we know this will be here
  }
}
```

**When making variables, use default values.** 
Meaning `const { loading = false, data = [] } = this.props`. This will help in data type consistencies.

**Handle asynchronous data more elegantly** 
Make sure to handle the pending / waiting state of your component. You could (for instance) use a `Loading` component that renders the content when loaded.

```js
render() {
  const { data = [] } = this.props
  return (
    <Loading loading={data.length > 0}>
      <MyComponent data={data} />
    </Loading>
  )
}
```

Where the loading component would be something like.

```js
const Loading = ({ children, loading = false, message = 'Loading...' }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <span>{message}</span>
  }
  return children
}
```

**You should catch exceptions** 
If you're writing something that you think could break or if you just want to be overly cautious you can use `try catch` blocks to catch exceptions in functional components.

```js
const MyComponent = ({ data = [] }) => {
  try {
    return <ul>{data.map( item => <li key={item}>{item}</li> )</ul>
  } catch (error) {
    const message = error.message || 'I broke!'
    return <span className="broken-component">{message}</span>
  }
}
```

In class components you can use

```js
componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
  // Handle error here.
}
```

[**The docs have a ton of great info if you'd like to learn more**](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Now, this is just a rudimentary example to describe what I am talking about. But it will help reduce your JS exceptions, which (when uncaught) will break your single page application. So you need to handle them. 
If a URL is invalid redirect to a 404 page. If a component needs data then wait for the data to render it. If you are trying to access a property on an object that is nested (especially if its from the server), aka `this.props.myData.obj.something.somethingelse`. Chances are that that object path wont always be there. You need to ensure that each of those aren't undefined or null.

**Extra credit** 
I've used lodash's `get` helper, which has helped me reduce exceptions!

```js
_.get(this.props, 'myData.obj.something.somethingelse') // returns `undefined` if the path is invalid
```

I guess the moral of the story is you should be proactive in your code to capture things that could break. :)

Comment: So the answer is "ship error-free code"?  I am a new React convert and I am thrilled about all the wins... but I've also been shipping software for twenty-five years and this attitude sounds naive.  Avoiding errors is a best practice of course, but the question is about *handling* errors—admittedly a lesser art form, but a necessary one nevertheless.  You don't control 100% of the code you ship.  You can't possibly foresee everything that could go wrong.  The OP and I would like to know what is the idiomatic way in React to deal with errors that *do* occur.

Comment: That said, your points here are valid.  The vast majority of errors that I see are the "deep access" kind you describe, and a "safe get" function could help mitigate that.  +1

Comment: @harpo sure, everyone always wants error free code. But what I am describing is a way to not only handle invalid data from the server (safe get method), but also a way to give UI for loading states. To your question about handling errors that do happen, you should have a notification component that shows user friendly messages around errors / failures. So for instance lets say you have a request you do and the request to load data fails. You should have a `catch` on that request and then `dispatch({type: NOTIFY_FAILURE...})` that reducer updates its information and then shows that somewhere.

Comment: @harpo a good example of a way to show something (not that you are using material design but its a good way to show user notifications) to users  could be this. http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/snackbar

Comment: John, thanks for the replies.  From the responses I've seen, "avoid errors" kind of *is* the "React way," and I didn't mean to pick on you.  Declarative rendering reduces probably 80% of bugs anyway, so why not eliminate the other 20% through good discipline?  For what it's worth, I wasn't actually having a problem with errors in my code, but was using component-testing components where I wanted to formally document certain "bad" conditions, and have the effects isolated to that test component.  Turns out you can use [unstable_handleError](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2461).

Comment: @harpo no worries didn't think you were picking on me :) Generally React applications are single page applications. and js errors cause those applications to break (like navigation wont work.. etc). So yea avoid errors is good. and handling errors when they do happen is good too. one thing you can also consider is create a base class that you extend from (instead of React.Component) and that base class render method can wrap the render in a try catch. :) `unstable_handleError is a cool method too :)

Answer (score 2):

For React v16 and up, the recommended way is to use error boundaries. This page (short and good)from the React team explains the feature: 
https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html. It includes a link to a codepen demo as well.

Answer (score 2):

A JavaScript error in a part of the UI shouldn’t break the whole app. To solve this problem for React users, React 16 introduces a new concept of an “error boundary”.

Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed. Error boundaries catch errors during rendering, in lifecycle methods, and in constructors of the whole tree below them.

A class component becomes an error boundary if it defines a new lifecycle method called `componentDidCatch(error, info)`

[ref link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html)